# Chain of delegatecall and call

Tags: solidity, delegatecall

Situation is: A calling B delegate calling C calling D

What would be the msg.sender in D?

I  performed some test in Remix and it looks like msg.sender in D is C's address. I don't get why it's not A's address.

Answer (score 2):

After I run the test code on [Remix](https://remix.ethereum.org/), it shows that the above answer is incorrect, it should be

```
A -> B (call) msg.sender = A (updates happen on B's storage)
B -> C (delegatecall) msg.sender = A (updates happen on B's storage)
C -> D (call) msg.sender = B (updates happen on D's storage)
```

Just try to run the following code yourself

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0

pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;


contract B {
    function callMe(address c, address d) public {
        c.delegatecall(
            abi.encodeWithSignature("callMe(address)", d)
        );
    }
}

contract C {
    event CalledC(address who);

    function callMe(address d) public {
        emit CalledC(msg.sender);

        D(d).callMe();
    }
}

contract D {
    event CalledD(address who);

    function callMe() public {
        emit CalledD(msg.sender);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why would it be? C is not `delegatecall`ing D, so msg.sender will be C in that call.

```
A -> B (call) msg.sender = A
B -> C (delegatecall) msg.sender = A
C -> D (call) msg.sender = C
```

Comment: My reasoning might be wrong, but if the delegatecall is executed in the context of B, then the call to D should get the B's msg.sender.

Here it looks like as soon as you doing a call, the "delegate chain" got broken.

Thanks for your reply.